# Trigger doesn't work - why?

Tags: sql, triggers

I don't know why this doesn't work and throws a 1064 error

```
delimiter $$
CREATE or remplace TRIGGER verifyExist BEFORE INSERT ON entreprise
    For each row 
    BEGIN
        IF new.numeroSiret in (
            select numeroSiret
            From entreprise
            where numeroSiret = new.numeroSiret
        ) THEN

UPDATE entreprise
SET nomEntreprise = new.nomEntreprise, adresse= new.adresse, ville = new.ville, commentaire = new.commentaire, entrepriseCreer = new.entrepriseCreer
WHERE idEntreprise = New.idEntreprise  ;



        END IF;       
    END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: assuming this is a copy paste, you have several misspelled words, including command type words.  That's of course assuming command words don't change depending on language, which I'm unclear on

Comment: delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER verifyExist BEFORE INSERT ON entreprise
    For each row 
    BEGIN
        IF new.numeroSiret in (
            select numeroSiret
            From entreprise
            where numeroSiret = new.numeroSiret
        ) THEN

UPDATE entreprise
SET nomEntreprise = new.nomEntreprise, adresse= new.adresse, ville = new.ville, commentaire = new.commentaire, entrepriseCreer = new.entrepriseCreer
WHERE idEntreprise = New.idEntreprise  ;



        END IF;       
    END;$$
DELIMITER ;

Comment: this working, but i already have error when i try to insert an new company ( entreprise = company)

Answer (score 0):

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER verifyExist BEFORE INSERT ON entreprise
    For each row 
    BEGIN
        IF new.numeroSiret in (
            select numeroSiret
            From entreprise
            where numeroSiret = new.numeroSiret
        ) THEN

UPDATE entreprise
SET nomEntreprise = new.nomEntreprise, adresse= new.adresse, ville = new.ville, commentaire = new.commentaire, entrepriseCreer = new.entrepriseCreer
WHERE idEntreprise = New.idEntreprise  ;



        END IF;       
    END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```